# cocos2d How to improve png alpha channel in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I imported my artwork in the simulator and this is how it looks like:

[image]

The alpha channel is not honored in the simulator.
The pnb is made on a win xp machine in Photoshop and imported 
on a mac.

Is this only a simulator issue? I don't have a device to test.

In case its not simulator specific, what should I do to improve the png quality?

Comment: Test it on a device. The Simulator will show this "banding" effect much more pronounced than devices. Take for example the YETIPIPI game's watery background (http://www.yetipipi.de). It looks fine on device, on Simulator the background is a total mess, the background is divided into 13 clearly visible and different horizontal color bands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will also happen on devices too. The phenomenon is called 'colour-banding', caused by the limited number of bits used to represent each colour channel, and affects all images but especially images with slow gradients. You can lessen the effects by applying some dithering algorithms (I believe that the TexturePacker tool has some post-processing dithering capabilities). See [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dithering) for an example of the effect of some dithering algorithms.